# emacs shell mode (M-x shell)

Tags: emacs

When I am using the emacs M-x **shell** mode I see strange characters on my screen which I believe are related to my prompt (which includes an End-Of-Line) and the use of colors.

So, here's what I see on the terminal:

```
mperdikeas@thorin:~#
$
```

And here's what I see inside Emacs **shell** buffer:

```
^[]0;mperdikeas@thorin: ~^Gmperdikeas@thorin:~#
$
```

Here's the relative section of my **.bashrc**:

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
  PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[1;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[1;33m\]\w\[\033[00m\]#\n$'
else
  PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w#\n$ '
fi
```

How can I configure emacs to properly display the prompt in the **shell** buffer?

Comment: Have you tried `M-x terminal-emulator`?

Comment: the display is even worse than when using M-x shell

Comment: You are right, the garbage is leftovers of ESC sequences for setting colors and such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further building on [DaveEmme's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/61850/24044) here's what I finally put in my `.bashrc` to keep things simple:

```
case "$EMACS" in
    t)
    PROMPT_COMMAND=
    PS1="[\u@\h:\w]$ "
esac
```

Relying on the value of `$TERM` didn't work in my case whereas Emacs [is required to set the $EMACS environment variable to true](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7130083/274677) for any shells it spawns.

Answer (score 7):

There's probably a more elegant solution, but this works for me. After any prompt-related lines in .bashrc, insert the following, adjusting the value of PS1 to suit:

```
# Keep it simple if running in emacs.
case "$TERM" in
  dumb)
    PROMPT_COMMAND=
    PS1="\u@\h:\W$ "
esac
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you'd better enable ansi-color in your shell-mode settings.

```
 (eval-after-load 'shell
   '(progn
      (autoload 'ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on "ansi-color" nil t)
      (add-hook 'shell-mode-hook 'ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on t)
      t))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling support for OSC (Operating
System Codes) by putting the following in your init file and restarting Emacs:

```
(add-hook 'comint-output-filter-functions 'comint-osc-process-output)
```

For more info see the *Shell Mode* section of the Emacs manual with `C-h i` followed by `m Shell Mode <RET>`:

> By default, Shell mode handles common ANSI escape codes (for
> instance, for changing the color of text).  Emacs also optionally
> supports some extend escape codes, like some of the OSC (Operating
> System Codes) if you put the following in your init file:
>
> ```
> (add-hook 'comint-output-filter-functions 'comint-osc-process-output)
> ```